# How do i pass data from jwt after login into a differerent screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jwt

I get `Access` and `user` from my JWT Token which logs in successfully, but the problem is that I can only access `user` in the Login Screen, I want to pass that data(user) to a different screen, Account Screen (Actually the API endpoint of Account Screen).

```
function LoginScreen(props) {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const auth = useAuth();
  const [loginFailed, setLoginFailed] = useState(false);

  const handleSubmit = async ({ username, password }) => {
    const result = await authApi.login(username, password);
    
    if (!result.ok) return setLoginFailed(true);
    setLoginFailed(false);
    console.log(result.data.access);
    auth.logIn(result.data.access);
    
    x = result.data.user; //This is the information I need in another screen
    console.log(x);
  };
```

**and this is my API endpoint which I call into AccountScreen to display the user's information, So i need to get that user from LoginScreen and pass it to the username below**

```
import client from "./clientAccount";

const username = "que";
const username3 = username.toString();
const endpoint = `/users/${username}/`;
const getUser = (username) => client.get(endpoint);

export default {
  getUser,
};
```

I have tried React Context, but only seems to work in render, I tried Redux but i dont understand it yet.

Comment: save login token in asyncstorage when logged in...when you navigate to other screen, by using that token, fetch user data..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to accomplish this. The simplest and ideal way will be to store the data in **local storage** or **session storage**, depending on the nature of the application, upon user logged in. Moreover, it is important to remove the user-specific information from the storage once the user logs out.

An example on how to store data on local storage:

```
localStorage.setItem('user', userName); // userName will be  information you need to store, e.g your result.data.user
```

and how to fetch the data:

```
localStorage.getItem('user')
```

However, in react-native, there is **no local storage** but you can use something like https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage or other available storages.

PS: *Sorry, at first, I missed the react-native tag.*

Comment: Hi, just noticed something. It gets the item fine. But doesn't work in my AccountScreen until I reload the screen

Comment: Can you check in your AccountScreen whether you are trying to fetch the item before actually setting it? I am assuming, in the account screen, you will set the key after the API call.